# What additional challenge maps are available for Batman:Arkham Asylum?

Tags: batman-arkham-asylum

I loved Batman:Arkham Asylum and am wondering what are the additional challenge maps available for it?  I can't seem to find an authoritative list anywhere.  The challenge maps I have seen appear to be duplicates of ones I've already played, just in different settings.  What is different/unique about each map, i.e., why would I want to play each one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Similar question from [Yahoo! Answers](http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20100519185323AATt5FB)

You can find a list of DLC for the Xbox360 [here](http://marketplace.xbox.com/en-US/games/media/66acd000-77fe-1000-9115-d802534307f6/?p=1&of=3&bt=0&sb=1#offers)
You can find a list of DLC for the PS3 [here](http://us.playstation.com/games-and-media/add-ons/batman-arkham-asylum-prey-in-the-darkness-map-pack.html)

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Batman:_Arkham_Asylum#Development_and_marketing)

> The Insane Night map pack was released
>   on September 17, 2009 for PlayStation
>   3 and Xbox 360 and features the
>   Totally Insane "FreeFlow" combat map
>   and the Nocturnal Hunter "Predator"
>   map.
>
> The second free pack, Prey In The
>   Darkness, was released on September
>   23, 2009 for PlayStation 3 in the
>   North America, and both consoles in
>   the EU.
>
> The Collector's Edition included an
>   exclusive preorder challenge map from
>   GameStop was announced called Dem
>   Bones. It places Batman under the
>   influence of Scarecrow's 'fear toxin'
>   causing him to hallucinate and all the
>   enemies to be seen as skeletons.